# On using external font in android my Application closes autometically

Tags: android, typeface

I am trying external font in my application but Application crash automatically.

I am using the code

Typeface face;

```
face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.otf"); 

textview.setTypeface(face);
```

its working but if i switch this activity more frequently then it crashes..

Give me solution....

Please help me...

Comment: What does LogCat show? Is there an exception stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Enclose this code in `try { } catch { }` block and see what exception it throws. This will help you a lot.
Also you can just run the app in debug mode and when it crashes, you will see the `e` var in the variables tab.

Comment: +1. Since Android runs in Java VMs, it might be good to learn Java.

Comment: thanks Alex..

I have tried with try{} and catch{} block but the control is not going into catch part.

can this error because of memory problem..?

Comment: @TK Kocheran. Actually, Android runs in the Dalvik VM. Java is compiled to class files that are "dexed" to run on the Dalvik VM.